# A tool to automatically change and save a copy of XML files

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, automation

I need a tool capable of taking a template XML file and replicating it several times,each time with different values in various fields.

Bonus points if the tool has some sort of API and can be integrated with c# applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for an XSLT processor.  There are several.

Since you want to integrate it with C#, you'd be best served using MSXML and the `XslCompiledTransform` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx

More documentation on XSLT from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14689742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There are other processors available though, such as Saxon or Xalan.  These could be used as a 'stand alone version' (or you could write a very simple console application in .NET that would take in an XSLT file and XML file(s) as a parameter and run the transformation repeatedly).

Saxon for home and personal use is available here: http://saxon.sourceforge.net/.  Commercial versions are also available.  Xalan can be found here: https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/

Comment: Noted, thanks. Any recommendations for stand-alone tools that do this job?

Comment: Edited to add that information.